# Is a function that unpacks lists possible?

Tags: list, haskell, types

I have the following problem, I want to write a function that generates nested lists and then unpacks the nested lists into a single list.

A function that generates nested lists of a dynamic degree depending on its arguments obviously does not type-check, as the return type would vary depending on the arguments. However is it possible to recursively unpack lists to always return a flat list?

Suppose the non-possible function would return this for an argument of 2:

```
[ [ [a], [b] ], [ [c], [d] ] ]
```

and this for an argument of 3:

```
[[[[a], [b], [c]], [[d], [e], [f]], [[g], [h], [i]]], [[[j], [k], [l]], [[m], [n], [o]], [[p], [q], [r]]], [[[s], [t], [u]], [[v], [w], [x]], [[y], [z], [a1]]]]
```

Now I would like to have some function that I can put into the recursive call that would result in something like this:

```
[ unpack [ unpack [a], unpack [b] ], unpack [ unpack [c], unpack [d] ] ]
```

which in turn would evaluate to `[a, b, c, d]`

I was able to write something like this for list of only one element:

```
unpack [x] = x

f 1 = [0]
f n = [unpack $ f x | x <- [1..n-1]]

*Main> f 3
[0,0]
```

But obviously it fails for 4:

```
*Main> f 4
[0,0,*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function unpack
```

Manual "trace":

```
f 3 = [unpack $ f x | x <- [1..3-1]]
    = [ unpack $ f 1, unpack $ f 2]
    = [ unpack [0], unpack [f x | x <- [1..2-1]]]
    = [ unpack [0], unpack [f 1] ]
    = [ unpack [0], unpack [0] ]
    = [0, 0]
```

Is such a function theoretically possible? I have a strong feeling that not... but maybe that feeling is wrong.

If it has not become clear yet what I have in mind: This `[unpack [1,2,3]]` would result in the list `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: `length [unpack [1,2,3]] == 1`, but `length [1,2,3] == 3`, so equating these two is contradictory

Comment: Not if `unpack` gets evaluated before `length`, is it not?

Comment: length is independent on the evaluation of the list elements (as long as that doesnt crash the program). Doesn't matter how you imlement unpack

Comment: So it is impossible even semantically due to contradiction. But... I mean... I can perform this function manually... why? What is the central error here?

Comment: what do you think `unpack [1,2,3]` by itself should evaluate to?

Comment: Yes, that is where I got stuck when writing `unpack`. In Python I would make it a generator.

Comment: Let's try a different question. What would the type of that function be?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Possibly some construct that I am unaware of, that is why I am asking. I could not write it with what I know so far, but I also could not be sure that there is no construct that would allow this. Just as a generator in Python.

Comment: So you want to flatten a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the comments, the program you want is not possible in Haskell.

Here's a possible alternative: Create a datatype

```
data Unpack a = Unpack [Unpack a] | Elem a
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Further you can write a function which evaluates the unpacking:

```
unpacked :: [Unpack a] -> [a]
unpacked [] = []
unpacked (Unpack x : xr) = unpacked x ++ unpacked xr
unpacked (Elem x : xr) = x : unpacked xr
```

Let's make the output prettier:

```
instance Show a => Show (Unpack a) where
  show (Unpack xs) = show xs
  show (Elem x)    = show x
```

Example usage in ghci:

```
> list = [Unpack [Elem 1, Unpack [Elem 3, Elem 4]], Unpack [Elem 5, Elem 6, Elem 7]]
[[1,[3,4]],[5,6,7]]

> unpacked list
[1,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: FWIW, this is a rose tree (with values only at the leaves) and the `toList` you would get by implementing `Foldable` for it.

Comment: One might object to that `Show` instance, since the shown “nested lists” aren't actually valid Haskell code. Although it's [possible to _make_ them valid Haskell, using the `-XOverloadedLists` extension](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113238/is-it-true-ask-jelly/113416#113416).